# How to stop JScrollPane from auto scrolling to bottom on initial display?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a JScrollPane wrapped around a JTextArea. When I populate the JTextArea, it automatically scrolls to the bottom. I want it to be at the top.

Here's the code that creates them:

```
    caption=new JTextArea();
    caption.setLineWrap(true);
    caption.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    scrollCaption=new JScrollPane(caption);
    scrollCaption.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180,20));
    scrollCaption.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,20));
```

And here's the code that populates it:

```
    int fontsize=scrollCaption.getHeight()/4;
    if (fontsize<10) fontsize=10;
    caption.setFont(caption.getFont().deriveFont((float)fontsize));
        
    String path=textfile.getAbsolutePath();
    List<String> lines=Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path));
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    for (String line : lines)
    {
        sb.append(line).append('\n');
    }
    caption.setText(sb.toString());
    int scrollmax=scrollCaption.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum();
    // scrollCaption.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);
    scrollCaption.getViewport().setViewPosition(new Point(0,0));
```

I tried saying getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0) and it still scrolled to the bottom. Then I tried getViewPort.setViewPosition(new Point(0,0)) and it still scrolled to the bottom. Maybe I'm doing these too soon? That there's some sort of "autoscroll to bottom" that's happening after I do this? But I don't know when else I could catch it.

One other clue: If I scroll to the top, and then resize the window, it stays scrolled to the top.

I'm running in Java 8.

Comment: From (very poor) memory, I think you can disable the caret - but you can also set the caret position to 0 to move back to the top

Comment: You have 3 copies of the file in memory: 1) in the List, 2) in the StringBuilder and 3) in the Document of the text area. I would suggest you can just use the `read(...)` method of the JTextArea to load the data. ***Maybe I'm doing these too soon?*** - some Swing methods will add code to the EDT by using invokeLater(...). So yes, it is possible that the setViewPosition(...) or setValue(0) code is executing before the Document is built completely. If the setCaret(0) suggestion doesn't work, then try wrapping either of the 3 suggestions in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater().

Comment: @camickr I changed the code to use JTextArea.read, which works. (I wasn't aware that function existed until yesterday.) So yeah, my program is working now, but I still don't understand why the version I had didn't work. And one can easily imagine scenarios where the JTextArea is populated by something other than simply reading a file, so I'm sure I'll hit this problem again sooner or later.

Comment: @Jay *so I'm sure I'll hit this problem again sooner or later* - and you were given the solution to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...).

Comment: @camickr True, I have 3 copies of the file. But only briefly. Once the function exists the list and StringBuilder will be eligible for garbage collection. If I wanted to process the file contents in memory, is there a better way to read it? (I used to do a lot of Java but that was 15 years ago. Now I only do Java on rare occasions so I'm pretty rusty.)

Comment: @camickr Ok, I'll try the invokeLater and see if that works.

Comment: @Jay *so I'm sure I'll hit this problem again sooner or later* - and you were given a suggestion to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...). *If I wanted to process the file contents in memory* - define process in memory? The entire file is in memory. It is in the Document of the text area. Your requirement determines your approach. Even with this question you don't need the StringBuilder. You just iterate through the List and `append(...)` the text to the text area.

Comment: @camickr I mean, suppose I want to manipulate the data in some way, not just read it in and dump it to a JTextArea. I've written plenty of programs that read text from a file and then do something with it other than just display it on the screen as is. Like last week I was working on a program that replaces tokens with values from a database, so we can have message templates that we customize on the fly. A few weeks ago I wrote a program that read a text file and parsed the data into a complex data structure. Etc.

Comment: @camickr "append text to the text area" Good point.

Comment: Sadly, invokeLater didn't work. I ran with a debugger and it executed, but it didn't move the scroll area.

Comment: *invokeLater didn't work* - post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. So you need a frame with a JTextArea and a JButton. When you click the button the source of your java class will be read into the text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution.

```
caption.setCaretPosition(0);
```

Like many programming problems, it's simple when you know how to do it.

I still don't understand why viewport.setLocation doesn't work. Elsewhere in the same program I use that exact same function to scroll the same text box. But whatever.

Comment: There is no setCaretLocation(...) method.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, setCaretPosition. Fixed.